# Need to Call a Method When the Device BecomeActive

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.2

I need a help from you, That is I am implementing an application in that I need to call a method once the app resign and  becomeActive but it is not working. Is there any way to call a method from our viewController when the device become active.

Thanks in advance.
Sekhar Bethalam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your VC is created, add an observer for the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` notification (and any others you may wish to react to) and have it perform a selector when it receives that notification on your VC (or some other object you know about at that time).